# Acess is denied on android studio v3.4

Tags: android-studio

When I click start debug, I got an error message :

> build intermediates transforms dexBuilder debug 108 com sec Test D.dex(Access is denied)

1. I started to debug again after removing build folder
2. I tried to use Invalidate Caches/restart

But I couldn't resolve the issue.
How could I do that?

Comment: Upgradle your gradle distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties this `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
` and enable online gradle build

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked well after update

Comment: Glad to know that. I have added it to the answer. Kindly mark it accepted and close the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your Gradle distribution URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Also, enable online Gradle build.